# Не получается включить переадресацию на https

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

Сайт на самописном php фреймворке. Все файлы самого сайта находятся в папке public. Соответственно получается 2 .htaccess файла. Структура httdocs https://prnt.sc/sli4y0
Вот так выглядит .htaccess в httpdocs https://prnt.sc/sli580
Видно что нас редиректит ко фронтенд файлам в /public
В паблике тоже есть свой .htaccess (второй), ниже код

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On



#Http redirect with www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#Http redirect without www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Https redirect with www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Https redirect without www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}_system42.php [NC,L]
```

Проблема заключается в том, что на сайт можно попасть через http, стандартные решения не работают, как правильно сделать редирект в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

пропишите редирект в настройках виртуалхоста. в `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
# редирект с http на https
Redirect / https://mysite.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
# тут ваш https
</VirtualHost>
```